# MRIs of tendinopathies

Tags: data-request, medical, images

I am looking for a dataset containing MRIs showing tendons with as many following fields as possible:

- diagnosis ( e.g., normal tendon, minor tendinopathy, etc.)
- MRI device model (I am especially interested in how many Teslas it has)
- year
- patient demographics
- which tendon(s) are affected

Answer (score 1):

https://radiopaedia.org/encyclopaedia/cases/musculoskeletal?lang=gb&modality=MRI&page=1 contains ~3k MRIs of musculoskeletal disorders, including tendinopathies.

[License: Creative Commons Attribution-Non-commercial-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License](https://radiopaedia.org/licence?lang=gb).